# onclick function react js rendering all divs with same info instead of the specific div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

So I'm not quit sure how to make myself clear on this question since I'm not the best at english. But okay here's my problem: I have divs with their personal info like url, title etc. When I click the info button I want to show more info for that specific element, but instead I get the same info in every div. Let me show my code to make it more clear.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useKeycloak} from "@react-keycloak/web";

const ProjectInfo = ({getProjectInfo}) => {
    const {keycloak} = useKeycloak()


    return (
        <div>
            {getProjectInfo.title}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProjectInfo;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {useKeycloak} from "@react-keycloak/web";
import ProjectInfo from "./ProjectInfo";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

const ProjectPage = () => {
    const {keycloak} = useKeycloak()
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [projectsList, setProjectsList] = useState([
        {projectId: "",projectUrl: "", description: '', projectTypes: "", title: ''}
    ])
    const [project, setProject] = useState(
        {projectId: "",projectUrl: "", description: '', projectTypes: "", title: ''}
    )


    const getProjectInfo = (id) => {
       let res = fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/get-one-project/' + id , {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token,
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                setProject(response)
            });
        if(res.status === 201) {
            navigate("/project-info")
        }
    }
        useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/user/users-projects/` + keycloak.tokenParsed.sub, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token,
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(data =>{
                setProjectsList(data)
            console.log(data)
        })

    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            {
                projectsList.map((p,index) => (
                    <ol key={index}>
                        <div className="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg mx-auto">
                            <div className="px-6 py-4">
                                <div>
                                {p.projectUrl}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {p.title}
                                </div>
                                <div>{p.projectId}</div>
                                <div className="font-bold text-xl mb-2">
                                    <button onClick={() =>
                                       getProjectInfo(p.projectId, index)}>info</button>
                                </div>
                                <p className="text-gray-700 text-base">
                                    <div>
                                    <ProjectInfo getProjectInfo={project}/>
                                    </div>
                                </p></div>
                            <div className="px-6 pt-4 pb-2"><span
                                className="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#photography</span>
                                <span
                                    className="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#travel</span><span
                                    className="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2">#winter</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ol>
                ))
            }

        </div>

    );
};

export default ProjectPage;
```

Comment: I figured it out but I don't know how to delete the question

Comment: The button to delete a question is o the bottom of your post.

Comment: Or you could answer your own question for the sake of others who face the same problem in the future.  They can search stack overflow and find your question and the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I posted the solution so others can see :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add an if statement like this:

```js
{
  project.projectId === p.projectId &&
  <ProjectInfo getProjectInfo={project}/>
 }
```